# Convert local path separators to forward slashes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, relative-path, os.path

I've got the paths of two files, like one HTML file and one CSS file. I want the former to contain a relative reference to the latter. I managed to use [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to obtain a relative path. But now I need to ensure that the path will always use forward slashes, even on Windows and possibly stranger platforms. I know that I can use `posixpath` to work with purely POSIX-style paths, but I don't see an official way to convert between path notations.

Would I do `path.replace(os.path.sep, posixpath.sep)`? Or are there some platforms where this would not work due to some strange escaping rules or some such? Should I decompose the path using [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) until the head becomes empty, and then use `posixpath.join` to recombine the parts, in order to maximize portability?